# PHP I/O Stream wrapper

Tags: php

Does PHP have a wrapping mechanism for I/O streams, typically represented by resource handles in the context of I/O functions such as `fwrite`?

Note, I'm not talking about [the Streamwrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) class, which is more of a filesystem wrapper + URI mapper. Or maybe I don't know I'm talking about it, it seems a peculiar implementation of both a data stream and filesystem in a single class... it's hard for me to figure out if it would work that way.

I'm talking of a class that handles a simple I/O data stream, much like sockets; something in the lines of:

```
/**** Error Logger ****/

class ErrorStream implements IOStreamInterface {
    function write($bytestream){
        sendByteStreamToDatabase($bytestream);
    }
}
class ErrorLogger {
    function getStream(){
        return new ErrorStream();
    }
}
```

```
/**** Application using Error Logger ***/

$stream=(new ErrorLogger())->getStream();
fwrite($stream,'I have an issue');
```

Comment: _"much like sockets"_ - Then why not just use [sockets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Because I don't want an INET or UNIX filesystem name-bound cross-process mammoth that needs a heapload of synchronisation and context switches just for dragging a few bytes around. Also sockets cannot be written like an I/O stream using `fwrite` afaik, one needs to use `socket_write`. I need a transparent replacement for I/O handles.